# Adding navigation bar to smaller view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Curious how the following navigation bar can be achieved using SwiftUI, does a UI that mimics the looks of navigation bar need to made or is there a way to add an actual NavigationView?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I think yes? Consider the following code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
            miniNavigationView
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
        .background(.red)
    }
    
    var miniNavigationView: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Inside the mini Navigation View!")
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Inside the mini Navigation view!")
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[Gif of Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i84m9.jpg)